# allow access only to homepage.html but deny direct access to other php files in the drectory

Tags: php, html, apache

i have 1.php, 2.php, 3.php under xampp/htdocs/example/

i have given the links to all three php files through the `<a href>` tag.

Is it possible to restrict direct access to all these php files. but they should work when they are accessed through homepage.html.
pls help

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a .htaccess file.
Make sure that you set your httpd.conf to allow and use .htaccess modifications.
Then you can set how files can or cannot be accessed.
Apache's website has good resources on this or google some things if you are not familiar with .htaccess. Very usefull for webdev.
[Apache.org tutorial](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html)